# How to format java code based on .editorConfig file?

Tags: java, coding-style, editorconfig

In a maven project (backend java + frontend angular) I would like to add a coding style and format code automatically (many file types), with a git pre-commit hook for example or/and at compile time.

I found some code style related plugins:

- [formatter-maven-plugin](https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/)
- [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/)
- [editorconfig-maven-plugin](https://ec4j.github.io/editorconfig-maven-plugin/)
- [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format)

But for each solution there is a problem (only java, without java linter, or opinionated). The `.editorConfig` seems the most complete configuration file, especially great for project which includes many different languages.

Sadly, the only plugin dealing with .editorconfig, `editorconfig-maven-plugin`, does not handle java, the plugin only comes with a yaml and xml linter.

**Question 1:** can we configure a Java linter for `editorconfig-maven-plugin` ? Any idea of a base to fork to write one ?

**Question 2:** Is there other tools to handle a java formatting based on .editorConfig ?

Any solution are welcome, even if not integrated with a maven plugin.

Comment: Sadly, Idea Intellij team told me they will not extract the java linter for now (which use .editoconfig) as it would be complicated (depend on a plugin management system), the request do not have enough vote.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `editorconfig-maven-plugin` doesn't support Java at the moment: for now the plugin has support to enforce coding style rules for other languages such as XML and YAML.

There are different Maven plugins that support Java linting, like the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` or the `PMD plugin`.

If you're looking for a tool to handle Java formatting based on `.editorConfig`, there are several options:

1. Eclipse IDE along with the Eclipse Code Formatter plugin.
2. IntelliJ IDEA IDE with the `EditorConfig` plugin
3. separate command-line tools such as the `JHipster` code generator or the `Jalopy` code formatter. These tools can be easily integrated into Maven build process to automatically format Java code based on the `.editorConfig` rules.

Comment: The goal is to not depend on any IDE. I saw that we could use Intellij as a binary and format code with CLI but a binary of 300Mo is not acceptable. Jalopy seems unmaintained since 8 years. For JHipster, I don't understand, they do not provide any code formater.

Comment: Does not it sound controversial: you want to use __editor__Config file, but outside of any editor. Looks to me this file is not intended for linting (I would say it just defines indents and simple rules). It could be much easier to set the same indentation rules in  `maven-checkstyle-plugin` config and use it as a more conventional way.

Comment: I don't think so, the .editorconfig file has become a standard, not linked to any tool. The great thing with this format is that you can describe many languages. Checkstyle plugin can only give the rules for java code, and can format only java code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "Adapter for Eclipse Code Formatter"?
You can export warps

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-adapter-for-eclipse-code-formatter

Than use export with formatter-maven-plugin
https://code.revelc.net/formatter-maven-plugin/examples.html#custom-configuration-file

[image]

Maybe "Save Actions" helps to achieve your goals earlier in the development process.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions